# Control android devices remotely

Tags: remote-control, multiple-devices

For an education purpose I've got multiple android devices (over 10 and they all are identical) and have to make them make the same actions simultaneously (like running app, click controls and so on).

A typical scenario is

1. Open an edu application on all devices
2. Navigate to a specific theme
3. Interact with content (play video, scroll text a requested position)

Is there web services or any other solutions to achieve such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get auto clicker apps that can be setup on each device, My personal favourite is  [HiroMacro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prohiro.macro&hl=en)

Another noteworthy one would be
[Android Bot Maker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.frapeti.androidbotmaker&hl=en)

Hiro is better for touch based automation however ABM is better for full control.

Both these suggestions require root access on all of your devices to work

You would simply setup the first device and then export the data to an SD Card, Applying the data to all programs on each device.

I'm sure most of the answers you are looking for will require root access to manage things like clicking and keyboard access automatically.

I hope this answers your question